# How do I connect to the database server?

Tags: php, sql-server

I need to connect my PHP code to SQL Server, I am using WAMP server with PHP v5.3.0, apache 2.2.11.

I have downloaded SQLSRV30.EXE and copy the files to ext folder of PHP, and also to Apache bin directory, in the php.ini I have added the following extensions:

```
 extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll 
 extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
```

Without the `;`, but I still getting the following message:

```
Fatal error:Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in 
C:\wamp\www\TPphp\SQLServer\tp.php on line 7.
```

I think that the libraries are not loading.

**What should I do to connect to the SQL Server using PHP?**

Comment: Have you restart the Web server after ini changes.

Comment: yes but i still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Is your wamp 64 bit?Change it to 32 bit version,because SQL driver from Microsoft are not compatible.
And you can use phpinfo(); to see if the libraries are loaded.
I can`t comment,so I wrote this as an answer.

Comment: i have installed wamp Wampserver2.4-x86 contains Apache Version :2.4.4  
PHP Version :5.4.16 and i have repeated the same previous steps and still the same problem